# Android Application Background Resolution

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable, screen-resolution

I want to design a background for android application using Photoshop , let's say I have Samsung S4,So I set the resolution to the maximum of that device which is 1080x1920 and 441dpi

Now,my question is where should i insert it in what subfolder of Resources and depending on what we choose that folder

-drawable-hdpi
-drawable-ldpi
-drawable-mdpi
-drawable-xhdpi
-drawable-xxhdpi

What image feature decides on which folder image should be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this image will show you which category it falls into:
[image]

As you can see everything larger than 400dpi is xxhdpi, so you should place it there.

Also check out the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) page.

EDIT: To answer your last question. There isn't any image feature that determines where it belongs, the folders are simply used to load images with different resolutions onto different screens. For example if the picture containing text has high resolution and you place it on a low density screen, the text would be (physically) too small to read. So you place a higher resolution image in hdpi or xhdpi folder and resize it so it has smaller resolution and place it in ldpi and mdpi folders.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this, it is from google!
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 1):

You should put on drawable-xxhdpi folder.

A brief explanation about the drawable resources:

The drawable resources are, by default, divided in 6 generalized groups based on its pixel density:

- **ldpi**: Low density drawables (~120 dpi)
- **mdpi**: Medium density drawables (~160 dpi)
- **hdpi**: High density drawables (~240 dpi)
- **xhdpi**: XHigh density drawables (~320 dpi)
- **xxhdpi**: XXHigh density drawables (~480 dpi)
- **xxxhdpi**: XXXHigh density drawables (~640 dpi)

The scaling ration between these drawables should be 3:4:6:8:12:16

You only need to provide density-specific drawables for bitmap files (.png, .jpg, or .gif) and Nine-Path files (.9.png). If you use XML files to define shapes, colors, or other drawable resources, you should put one copy in the default drawable directory (`drawable/`).

Even if you don't provide alternative drawable resources for the different groups of density, the Android system will find the best matching drawable and scale it for you. But is recommended to provide alternative drawable resources in order to ensure to always have smooth drawables in all devices.

You might want to take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).